# AngularJS - ng-click has no stop propogation

Tags: angularjs

When click on parent div, it is working fine(i.e only fun1() is calling). 
When I click on inner div(test4), both the functions fun1() and fun2() are calling, but I want to call only fun2() when I click on inner div.

```
<div ng-click="fun1()">
    <div>test1</div>
    <div>test2</div>
    <div>test3</div>
    <div ng-click="fun2()">test4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngClick` directive (as well as all other event directives) creates `$event` variable which is available on same scope. This variable is a reference to JS event object and can be used to call `stopPropagation()`

Try this
        `<div ng-click="fun2(); $event.stopPropagation()">test4</div>`

Heres the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jlEjDBZbXP0AkQFbZWxE?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

Working plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:8rFfZljYNl3z1A4LKSL2?p=preview

First you need to explicitly pass $event and then call stopPropagation() on it

```
  <div ng-click="fun2($event)">test4</div>

  $scope.fun2 = function(event){
    console.log("Fun2")
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
```

Comment: Different ways to skin a cat. +1  :)